# Angular ngx-translate - check if translation key exists directly in HTML template

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate

I want to translate some values in my Angular HTML template using `ngx-translate` and `| translate` pipe. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
<div>
{{equipment.type.name}}
</div>
```

where `equipment` is an object from component.ts. So only a name of the eqipment type is being displayed.

What I want to acheive is to translate these types of equipment, so I added some translations to my i18n json file:

```
  "EQUIPMENT-TYPE": {
    "chair": "Chair",
    "table": "Table",
  }
```

I have modified my HTML template as below:

```
<div>
{{'EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name | translate}}
</div>
```

and it actualy works, but only when there is a translation added to the i18n json files.

**My question is: Is it possible to check if a specific translation key exists in the json file and if not, to dsplay just a name of the equipment type?**

Below code doesn't work, it always tries to translate the key, even if it doesn't exists:

```
<div>
{{ ('EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name) ?  ('EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name | translate) : equipment.type.name }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in ngx-translate if translation does not exist the string of the key will be retured directly, so try this :

```
{{ ('EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name | translate) !== 'EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name  ?  ('EQUIPMENT-TYPE' + equipment.type.name | translate) : equipment.type.name }}
```

if the translation does not exist translateService will return the string directly, so

```
 this.translateService.instant('stringToBeTranslated') is equal to stringToBeTranslated// it does not exist
```

but when you add it to your json

```
'stringToBeTranslated': "test"

this.translateService.instant('stringToBeTranslated) is equal to test
```